# how to add Content Security Policy (CSP)

Tags: javascript, http, content-security-policy

I want to access a website using javascript. but I am getting the following error in the console.

> Refused to connect to 'https://example.com' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I have added the following meta tag in the index.html,

> meta  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self' http://example.com;" />

Isn't this the right way to add CSP? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have one CSP published with the `default-src 'self'` policy. Quite possible it was done via HTTP header.
Check the [Helmet middleware](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/) settings in case of NodeJS server, or `Header set` in the `.htaccess` file in case on Apache server. In case of Nginx it can be `add_header` in the config.

By adding `<meta>` tag you just publish a second CSP, which does not overrides the first one. 2 CSPs works subsequently - all sources should pass both CSP.

Figure out where CSP is publushed and add `connect-src 'self' http://example.com;` there.